# Why does the typedefed struct fail to compile with NVCC?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

```
typedef struct {
    long long int mem_0;
} Tuple1;

typedef struct {
    int tag;
    union {
        struct Tuple1 Union0Case0;
    } data;
} Union0;
```

> C:/Users/Marko/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Multi-armed Bandit Experiments/SpiralExample/bin/Release/cuda_kernels.cu(10): error: incomplete type is not allowed

The above does in fact compile on the GCC 5.3.0 compiler. When I change it to this, it works:

```
struct Tuple1 {
    long long int mem_0;
};

struct Union0 {
    int tag;
    union {
        struct Tuple1 Union0Case0;
    } data;
};
```

Comment: the error seems perfectly reasonable to me. You want  `Tuple1 Union0Case0` within the union. At not point did you declare a named struct called `Tuple1`

Comment: I did not? Then what is that first typedef supposed to be?

Comment: It's an *unnamed* struct (no name follows the keyword `struct`).

Comment: Ah, I see. How convoluted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments into an answer so that this question falls off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag.

This:

```
typedef struct {
    long long int mem_0;
} Tuple1;
```

defines a type containing an *unnamed* structure. There is no definition of `struct Tuple1`.

This, on the other hand, defines such a structure:

```
struct Tuple1 {
    long long int mem_0;
};
```

and this defines a type containing such a named structure:

```
typedef struct Tuple1 {
    long long int mem_0;
} Tuple1_t;
```

Any of the latter two would be compatible with your other code.